# Passing Array parameter from C# to Oracle collection type of table

Tags: c#, asp.net, plsql, wcf-data-services, plsqldeveloper

I have declare a collection Table and record in PLSQL Specification.

> ```
>          type loan_recov_rec is  record(v_prncpl_ed_cd number(3),v_prncpl_recov number   (7),v_int_ed_cd number(3),
>      v_int_recov,number(5));
>
>
>
>   type loan_recov_tbl is table of loan_recov_rec index by binary_integer;
> ```
>
> procedure pr_final_settlement(v_loan_recov_tbl in loan_recov_tbl);

So, I pass the Array parameter from C# page

```
 cmd.ArrayBindCount = v_loan_recov_tbl.Length;
                Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter P_loan_recov = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter("v_loan_recov_tbl", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Int32);
P_loan_recov.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

P_loan_recov.CollectionType = Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
P_loan_recov.Value = v_loan_recov_tbl;
cmd.Parameters.Add(P_loan_recov);
```

using above code it not works it get's error `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Array'. v_loan_recov_tbl is an Array Parameter.`
Hear,I am using datatype as `OracleDbType.Int32` is it right or i have to decler other data type.I declare  Input parameter in Procedure as Table

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues. First you are working with a PL/SQL-defined record type and not an SQL-defined object type. ODAC wants SQL-defined object types. Second, assuming you had all the proper SQL-defined object types and C# custom types defined, there's an excellent example of c# code to work with array binding in the ODP.NET software stack on your machine: %ODAC_HOME%\odp.net\samples\4\AssocArray.