# odp.net run oracle stored procedure with output parameter of user defined parameter

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

This procedure has address_table out pkg.address_tab_type

```
create or replace
procedure hr.p_get_address
  (
    in_pid in number,
    address_table out pkg.address_tab_type
  )
as
  address_row pkg.address_rec_type;
  cursor address_cursor is 
    select
      addr.pid, addr.street, addr.city
    from
      hr.address addr
    where
      pid = in_pid;
begin
  row_count := 0;
  open address_cursor;
  loop
    fetch address_cursor into address_row;
    exit when address_cursor%NOTFOUND;
    row_count := row_count + 1;
    address_table(row_count) := address_row;
  end loop;
  close address_cursor;
end p_get_address;
```

My pkg declares custom address_rec_type and address_tab_type:

```
create or replace
package hr.pkg as
  type address_rec_type is
    record
    (
      pid address.pid%type,
      street address.street%type,
      city address.city%type
    );
  type address_tab_type is
    table of address_rec_type index by binary_integer;
end hr.pkg;
```

When I execute my stored procedure in SQL Developer everything work file. So, my proc. works. I need to call this procedure and get address_table in C# (ASP.NET). I am using odp.net. I am able to call procedure with refCursor, works fine. How do I call procedure with output parameter of a user defined type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Array parameter from C# to Oracle collection type of table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990262/passing-array-parameter-from-c-sharp-to-oracle-collection-type-of-table)

Comment: Not exactly... I know how to pass Array, but how do I process a return OUT parameter of user defined type from a stored procedure in C#. That the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to use package-defined record data types as parameters with ODP.NET. You can used database-defined types (i.e., defined using a CREATE TYPE statement) but answering how to do that is outside the scope of your question.

So your options are create database-defined types (and learn how to use the Abstract Data Type API of ODP.NET or to change your procedure parameter list as a decomposition the primative data types of the package-defined record data type.

Comment: How to do that is exactly what I am asking. I know how to do it in database with package or database defined types, what I don't know is how to process an OUT parameter from a stored procedure of UDT. That's what I am hoping to get from users of this site.

Comment: But that isn't your question above.

Comment: @user1863635 Michael was being a little sticky about answering the question as asked, as 'Chameleon Questions' can be irritating to answer, you spend time answering only to see the original be edited to a completely different question, or you answer what you meant, and other users complain you never answered the original question.

I doubt you care 8 years on, but correct behaviour would have been to re-ask the question correctly and accept this if it's correct.